# Circular Reference in Bean Class While Creating a Dataset from an Avro Generated Class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

I have a class `RawSpan.java` that is Avro generated from the corresponding `avdl` [defintion](https://github.com/hypertrace/data-model/blob/main/data-model/src/main/avro/RawSpan.avdl). I am trying to use this class to create a Dataframe to a `Dataset<RawSpan>` in Spark as:

```
val ds = df.select("value").select(from_avro($"value", "topic", "schema-reg-url")).select("from_avro(value).*").as[RawSpan]
```

However, I run into this error during deserialization:

`UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot have circular references in bean class, but got the circular reference of class class org.apache.avro.Schema`

The problem apparently happens [here](https://gist.github.com/pandepra/1e1ad28d33e1a00d5ee31f0ef49a9020#:%7E:text=public%20org.apache.avro.Schema%20getSchema()%20%7B%20return%20SCHEMA%24%3B%20%7D) (L19), as per a similar [question](https://gist.github.com/pandepra/1e1ad28d33e1a00d5ee31f0ef49a9020#:%7E:text=public%20static%20org.apache.avro.Schema%20getClassSchema()%20%7B%20return%20SCHEMA%24%3B%20%7D) asked earlier.

I found this [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25789) but the PR to address it was closed due to no activity. Is there some workaround to this? My Spark version is 3.1.2. I am running this on Databricks.